# Dynamic link not working after jQuery Ajax response

Tags: html, jquery

I have dynamic menu links that are created by ajax response. It only works when the page initially loads but not new ones. I've tried to bind it using .On but that isn't working. Please see code and markup. Hopefully someone has an idea why it won't bind.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("menu")){
                    $(".menu dd ul").hide();
                    $(".menu dt a").removeClass("selected");
                }

        });

        $(".menu dt a").on('click', function(e) {

            var clickedId = "#" + this.id.replace(/^link/,"ul");

                // Hides everything else that the current menu 
            $(".menu dd ul").not(clickedId).hide();

                //Toggles the menu.
            $(clickedId).toggle();

                //Add the selected class.
            if($(clickedId).css("display") == "none"){
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            }else{
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }

        });
});
```

And the markup is below.

```
        <div class="floatLeft" style="width:15px;">
            <dl style="" class="menu">
               <dt>
               <a class="" id="linkglobal_1" style="cursor: pointer;"></a><span class="result"></span></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul style="display: none;" id="ulglobal_1">
                        <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Only Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customize</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

Comment: is the markup you posted already there, or is it all loaded dynamically? as @Jai mentions, you have to deligate the click event. so jquery has to monitor the correct spot for the event. check [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the delegation part..

Comment: It's all loaded dynamically. But it works for my other things that I have ajaxed. Just not that menu. I used to use Live. But I have comment boxes and other jQuery links that are created with ajax that work fine.

Comment: you should post a link or a fiddle. that may help..

Comment: I can't post a link it's not in a public location. also I don't get why $(".menu dt a").live('click', function(e) { works but .On does not. I know live is deprecated but I might use it anyway since it works just fine. why is on so difficult to use versus live.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, see my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

event delegation needed this way:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menu dt a", function(e) {
```

Comment: Thanks but click is still not working. :( I'm not sure why. Only still works on the non ajax created elements.

Comment: AFter looking again at the jQuery docs, they use .On with document instead of a selector as so `$(document).on('click', ".menu dt a", function(e) {` after I changed it to use the document it worked. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: of course @document@ works.. see. now jquery is monitoring document. the WHOLE document. but you should get a selector closer to the element that is getting loaded. that the whole idea behind .on() compared to .live(). monitoring a smaller part than the whole document will increase performace a lot.